# Binding wpf listbox programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

What is the equivalent of this in c# code?

```
<ListBox Name="CategoryListBox"
     ItemsSource="{Binding OtherList}"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     Height="195"
     Margin="34,224,0,0"
     VerticalAlignment="Top"
     Width="120">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I tried somehing like this :

```
        ListBox CategoryListBox = new ListBox();
        CategoryListBox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        CategoryListBox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        CategoryListBox.Height = 420;
        CategoryListBox.Width = 300;
        CategoryListBox.Margin = new Thickness(22, 93, 0, 0);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(CategoryListBox, TextBox.DataContextProperty, new Binding("CategoryName") { Source = OtherList });
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(CategoryListBox, ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("OtherList") { Source = this });
```

but it doesn't work as it should because it shows only this:
[Link Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l7au.png)

And it should show CategoryNames: "Fist" "Second" "Third"

I think the problem is with my text binding inside ListBox but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please do elaborate on why would you want to bind programically? I cannot think of a single case that I would use binding programically if I would need to bind.

Comment: because im creating listbox dynamic for example when i click button and i need to bind it this way

Comment: Please read on `ObservableCollection` for such matter. There is a lot to learn but trust me it is worth a while. For more information [click.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Carl, it doesn't really matter why the OP wants to bind programmatically. His question isn't about best practices, it's about how to solve a particular use case. Also, using an `ObservableCollection` is a good idea if the list is going to change after the initial binding, but using an `ObservableCollection` isn't going to magically fix the rest of the code.

Comment: @DustinCleveland Good point. But that is the reason why I kept it as a comment instead of an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the data template programmatically as well. Then you can simply assign the data template to the ListBox's `ItemTemplate` property.

The data template could be created in XAML and loaded programmatically as well. This may make creating the template a little easier and more maintainable.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Category
    {
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Category> categories = new List<Category>
    {
        new Category { CategoryName = "Category 1" },
        new Category { CategoryName = "Category 2" }
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

        textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("CategoryName"));

        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate
        {
            VisualTree = textBlock
        };

        var categoryListBox = new ListBox
        {
            ItemTemplate = dataTemplate
        };

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(categoryListBox, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding
        {
            Source = categories
        });

        var grid = (Grid) this.Content;

        grid.Children.Add(categoryListBox);
    }
}
```

Edit: My first example wasn't creating a Binding to the `ItemsSource` property. I've updated the code snippet to do so.

Comment: You can also put the datatemplate into the resources of the window/usercontrol and access it using `(DateTemplate)this.Resources["KeyName"]`